# Why do two forms appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap, web2py

I am using jQuery and bootstrap to give drop-down search suggestions.Following is the html code.But when I type something in the search form and then clear the form.Two forms apears as in the picture.Why? I am new to jQuery. Thanks for any help.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <form class="form-search">
                <input type="text" id="month" name="month" class="input-medium search-query">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
                <div id="suggestions">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery("#month").keyup(function(){
      ajax('search', ['month'], 'suggestions')});
</script>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
I am using web2py framwork.This is the search function's code:

```
def search():
    if not request.vars.month: return dict()
    month_start = request.vars.month
    selected=complete('piracyfinder',month_start)  #this line get the search results
    return DIV(*[DIV(k['title'],
                     _onclick="jQuery('#month').val('%s')" % k['title'],
                     _onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='lightblue'",
                     _onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white'"
                     ) for k in selected])
```

Comment: what is the `ajax()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using the same function (i.e., `search()`) to fill in the suggestions as well as to create the form (though that function doesn't process the form when submitted). According to the logic, when `request.vars.month` is either empty or does not exist, the function returns an empty dict. This will result in the associated view (i.e., /views/[controller name]/search.html) being executed and returned. Presumably the search.html view contains the HTML code shown above. So, when you clear the input box, the keyup handler is triggered and sends an empty month variable, which results in a new copy of the form being sent back and inserted in the "suggestions" div. You can avoid this problem by checking whether `request.vars.month` exists:

```
if not request.vars.month:
    return '' if 'month' in request.vars else dict()
```

A better approach might simply be to use different functions for the search form and the suggestions given that they do completely different things and don't share any code.

Answer (score 0):

`if not request.vars.month` also applies to the `month` var existing but being empty. Therefore, it's returning the form.

You need to do one of these:

- Have your "suggestions" code be in a different page/file
- Add a `isAJAX` variable to the request (or some other way to identify AJAX requests)
- Check if the variable *exists*, rather than checking if it is falsy.